# How to generate 2D mesh from two 1D arrays and convert it into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example, I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([10, 11])
```

How can I generate a pandas dataframe with every combination of x and y, like below?

```
x      y
1     10
1     11
2     10
2     11
3     10
3     11
```

Comment: Well I don't know what you would use this for, but you may be interested in [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html). Whereas pandas is kind of opinionated as tabular data, xarray is like numpy w/labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([10, 11])


pd.DataFrame({'x':np.repeat(x,y.shape[0]),
              'y':np.tile(y,x.shape[0])})
```

yields:

```
   x   y
0  1  10
1  1  11
2  2  10
3  2  11
4  3  10
5  3  11
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pd.Multiindex.from_product`:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x, y])).reset_index()

   level_0  level_1
0        1       10
1        1       11
2        2       10
3        2       11
4        3       10
5        3       11
```

Or for some reason you want to call the method directly:

```
from pandas.core.reshape.util import cartesian_product

print (pd.DataFrame(cartesian_product([x, y])).T)

   0   1
0  1  10
1  1  11
2  2  10
3  2  11
4  3  10
5  3  11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([10, 11])

yv, xv = np.meshgrid(y, x)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=xv.ravel(), y=yv.ravel()))
```

output:

```
   x   y
0  1  10
1  1  11
2  2  10
3  2  11
4  3  10
5  3  11
```

Answer (score 2):

A comparison of proposed solutions using `benchit`:

```
#@Henry's solution
def m1(x, y):
  pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x, y])).reset_index()

#@anon01's solution
def m2(x,y):
  yv, xv = np.meshgrid(y, x)
  return pd.DataFrame(dict(x=xv.ravel(), y=yv.ravel()))

#@My Work's solution
def m3(x,y):
  return pd.DataFrame({'x':np.repeat(x,y.shape[0]),'y':np.tile(y,x.shape[0])})

#@yatu's solution
def m4(x,y):
  return pd.DataFrame(product(x, y), columns=['x','y'])


#@?'s solution (removed)
def m5(x,y):
  return pd.DataFrame([[j, i] for j in x for i in y], columns=['x','y'])

in_ = {n:[np.arange(n), np.arange(n)] for n in [10,100,1000,5000]}
```

Seems **m2** and **m3** are fastest for large arrays (m2 slightly faster).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take the cartesian product of both arrays via [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and build a dataframe from the result:

```
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(product(x, y), columns=['x','y'])

   x   y
0  1  10
1  1  11
2  2  10
3  2  11
4  3  10
5  3  11
```

Comment: itertools is much slower than the vectorized solutions tho

Comment: I wouldn't want to try it with `len(x) == len(y) == 10000` :)

Comment: I don't think OP is dealing with huge arrays,the amount of terms generated grows very rapidly. Not sure you'd be even able to fit the result into memory @anon01

Comment: A similar way is to use `pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x, y])).reset_index()` which is vectorised.

Comment: It's a fine solution, I was just pointing out the vectorized version will be more performant :)  `xv.data.nbytes/1e9` = 0.8, not too bad...

Comment: Yes, it will, agreed. You  might want to use `ravel` instead of `flatten` though to avoid creating those copies @anon01

Comment: Good one @HenryYik ! Post it as a soln :)

Comment: itertools product comes in handy when you are not dealing with only numbers, you could have text columns/data. numpy meshgrid turns everything into an object, and if you are going to build a dataframe, there is a cost associated with converting back to the original datatypes.